# simple_form adding class that is conflicting with my css. Need to remove class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, simple-form

I'm using Simple_form with Rails 5 and bootstrap 4. I'm having an issue where i've set my datatype to be :text

My bootstrap form brings in the class text as it should however this is making my form hide somewhere beneath something on the page. When I remove the text class and add a class of string it appears in the view.

whats the best option here? Just try to change the text class to be string class? 
or try amend the text class simple form is calling to something else text_new class or something so it doesn't conflict with something somewhere else?

here's the code I'm getting and result i'd like. I've tried adding

html: { class: "string"}

but this does nothing for me.

I essentially need the three instances of class "text" changed to "string" or better yet have it removed or changed to different name in a default setting please.

```
<div class="form-group text required testimonial_quote">
  <label class="control-label text required" for="testimonial_quote">
  <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Quote</label>
    <textarea class="form-control text required" name="testimonial[quote]" id="testimonial_quote"></textarea></div>
```

My Simple form code

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@testimonial) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :quote %>
    <%= f.input :received %>
    <%= f.association :course, label_method: :header %>
    <%= f.input :featured %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like  f.input :your_input, as: :text, :input_html => { :class => 'your_class' } ?

Comment: Ok so my just doing the as: :string on the form line I now get the string value as a class and no text value which will work but the styling is not text. At least the form line is showing now.

Answer (score 0):

Without you posting your existing simple_form code I can't give you the exact answer.  That said I think the line you are looking for is:

```
<%= input_html: { class: 'string' } %>
```

Example from the simple_form docs:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username, input_html: { class: 'special' } %>
  <%= f.input :password, input_html: { maxlength: 20 } %>
  <%= f.input :remember_me, input_html: { value: '1' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi @ruby_newbie, Sorry for not adding the original code. I'll emend it now. The input_html adds a class to the original classes already showing. I need a way to remove the "text" class from the form. Wonder if it is possible to do this instead of adding classes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below

1. `html: {...}` for form tag
2. `input_html: {...}` for input tag.
3. `class: "..."` for submit tag

For example:

```
<%= simple_form_for @product, html: { class: "ex-product-form" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'p-name' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi @Dapeng114, thanks for that however i'm getting a syntax error on the simple_form_for line. When I do the input_html: method I can only add another class. This still leaves the "Text" class and this class is what is causing the issue. Simple_form is adding this because I've the datatype set to "text" but I don't want the class added as its causing an issue in the form and not displaying the form line at all.

Comment: Hi Bradley, i see. But instead of removing class `text`, you can add a class `someclass` then change your default css to `input.text:not(.someclass)`. And style your new class as input.text.someclass`.